# Troubles with variables

Tags: javascript

I'm putting many local variables to global defined function. How I can do that? Here is some code.

```js
function error(code) {
  var errors = {
    1000: function() {
      return `Troubles with ${product}`
    },
    1001: function() {
      return 'error'
    }
    //And many errors with different variable names...
  }
  alert(errors[code]);
  //it returns error in console :(
}

function check() {
  var product = 'car';
  error(1000)
}
check();
```

Comment: I think you want `error('1000')` - keys for objects are referenced with a string not a number

Comment: @duxfox-- - True, but it'll get converted anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh I see, also @OP you want to execute the function that comes back from the object - `errors[code]()` but you don't have `product` defined anywhere. But I don't understand what you're asking/need help with

Comment: Product is defined in a different scope so it is not going to work with a simple reference. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't produce an error in the console, it alerts a function definition:

```js
function error(code) {
  var errors = {
    1000: function() {
      return `Troubles with ${product}`
    },
    1001: function() {
      return 'error'
    }
    //And many errors with different variable names...
  }
  alert(errors[code]);
  //it returns error in console :(
}

function check() {
  var product = 'car';
  error(1000)
}
check();
```

But if you *called* the function `error(1000)` returns, *that* would cause an error because `product` is not in scope. You need to pass it into the function. Probably the best way is to pass in an object with named properties that the template literal can use:

```js
function error(code, params) {
  var errors = {
    1000: function(params) {
      return `Troubles with ${params.product}`;
    },
    1001: function() {
      return 'error';
    }
    //And many errors with different variable names...
  }
  alert(errors[code](params));
}

function check() {
  var product = 'car';
  error(1000, {product});
}
check();
```

But I wouldn't define `error` that awy, there's no reason to re-create your `errors` object and its properties and functions every time you call `error`. Instead:

```js
const error = (() => {
  const errors = {
    1000(params) {
      return `Troubles with ${params.product}`;
    },
    1001() {
      return 'error';
    }
    //And many errors with different variable names...
  };
  return function error(code, params) {
    alert(errors[code](params));
  };
})();

function check() {
  var product = 'car';
  error(1000, {product});
}
check();
```

Comment: beat me to it :(

Answer (score 0):

Note that `product` is not available inside `1000`.If you think you can do that using closure then you are wrong. *Variables of the parent scope is available to the function where the function is declared not where its called*

You can should pass the product as argument

```js
function error(code) {
  var errors = {
    1000: function(product) {
      return `Troubles with ${product}`
    },
    1001: function() {
      return 'error'
    }
    //And many errors with different variable names...
  }
  return errors[code]
  //it returns error in console :(
}

function check() {
  var product = 'car';
  console.log(error('1000')(product));
  
  
}
check();
```